# Find the DNS server used for a certain domain

Tags: terminal, network, dns

Is there a way to see what DNS I've used to resolve a certain domain? I thought nslookup might've been able to do this but it simply tells me my router was my DNS — not what DNS It used. For example, I want to know if domain.tld was resolved using my default ISP DNS or by the Cloudflare DNS.

Backstory: I've been having some DNS trouble with my ISP. I fixed that by adding Cloudflare DNS 1.1.1.1 as my secondary in my modem.

Standard nslookup output for Google:

```
tim@iMac ~ % nslookup google.com
Server:     192.168.20.1
Address:    192.168.20.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.199.78
```

The only other way I could think of is using Cloudflare on my modem and my ISP DNS on my Mac and then nslookup should tell me what server it used. I can do this but I'm really looking for a way in terminal without diving into my modem settings.

Comment: What do you mean by "what DNS server is used"? macOS uses one of the DNS servers defined in Network settings (in round robin as far as I know). If you have trouble with some, just use the ones from Cloudflare or Google (8.8.8.8).

Comment: I know what servers I've got. I want to see what server was used, or is used for a particular website. For example, some sort of notification when my primary DNS failed to resolve the hostname.